Pick<Type, Keys> where Type is Partial<Type> allows to assign nonexistent properties
What I want to achieve
I want to get a subset of specific/predefined properties using Pick<Partial<Type>, Keys> on a provided Type. The predefined/specific properties may or may not exist on the provided Type, but if they don't we should not be allowed to assign it on the return type.
What I've tried
I tried creating a type SubsetPick<T extends Partial<PropertyType>> = Pick<T, Keys> but, probably due to the Partial<PropertyType> type, it returns Keys specified in Pick<T, Keys> even if they do not exist on the provided Type.
Example
Here is an example to reproduce what I'm trying to do:
interface Properties {
  name: string;
  animal: boolean;
  plant: boolean;
  fly: boolean;
  swim: boolean;
  walk: boolean;
}

type Bird = Pick<Properties, 'name' | 'animal' | 'fly'>;

// this doesn't work
type SubsetPick<T extends Partial<Properties>> = Pick<T, 'fly' | 'swim' | 'walk'>

// bad: we can assign properties `swim` and `walk` that don't exist on type `Bird`
const birdSubset: SubsetPick<Bird> = {
  fly: true,
  swim: true, // no error
  walk: true, // no error
}

Playground

I don't understand what the goal is. Your InferPick<T> is essentially just T, but for Plant it's undefined. But... you want const plant: InferPick<Plant> = undefined and not const plant: InferPick<Plant> = {}?  I'm not seeing the usefulness of Pick in there at all.

see prev comment.  Maybe you are looking for something like this playground link where you explicitly prohibit properties that you don't pick? But even this I'm assuming you want a plant to be {} and not undefined. Am I close? I could write an answer or find a duplicate question if this is what you're looking for. If not, please [edit] to clarify the intent.

@jcalz the Plant type was irrelevant and could attract to much attention on what I am trying to achieve, I updated the snippet to try to represent more clearly what I want... I want to be able to get a subset of specific properties using Pick<Type, Keys> on provided Type

Your ConditionalPick doesn't "work", though, it's just a no-op. You could write const bird: Bird =  and get the desired behavior in both cases, as shown in this playground link. Where is the issue?

The ConditionalPick isn't helping to demonstrate what you're looking for. Could you look at the PickOnly in this playground link and let me know if it's what you're looking for or not? I suppose you could split it into the original Pick and then later come back and try to exclude other stuff as shown in this playground link, but I'm not sure what that buys you.  Anyway, please look at those and let me know, since I think either or both might be what you're trying to achieve.

@jcalz thanks for putting some effort on my question, but I believe you focus too much on the sample and try to make sense of it when I only tried to represent with bogus types. I adjusted the beginning of the issue to explain that I want to be able to retrieve a subset of specific keys IF they exists on the provided type. Hope it make more sense...

Please read my previous comment and respond to it specifically.

Thanks @jcalz, your playground didn't fix my issue but inspired me to dig in another direction and I found the answer

I'm afraid your answer makes little sense to me, and neither does the question. It would help to know what the specific input/output types you're looking for are, but at this point, I imagine further comments and edits is unlikely to be fruitful, so I'll disengage. Sorry we couldn't communicate effectively!

I'm sorry if it wasn't clear enough, but I do appreciate the time and effort you put into this... you helped me find the solution.

I figured it out inspired by playground examples provided in @jcalz comments...
Using Extract<Type, Union> it is possible to extract only keys that are assignable to Type and avoid having unassignable properties in the return type. So instead of using Pick<Type, Keys> you can construct the return object with the proper type.
interface Properties {
  name: string;
  animal: boolean;
  plant: boolean;
  fly: boolean;
  swim: boolean;
  walk: boolean;
}

type Bird = Pick<Properties, 'name' | 'animal' | 'fly'>;

// this works
type SubsetPick<T extends Partial<Properties>> = {
  [P in Extract<keyof T, 'fly' | 'swim' | 'walk'>]: T[P];
};

// good: we can only assign property that exists on type `Bird`
// and that are part of the subset declared in `SubsetPick`
const birdSubset: SubsetPick<Bird> = {
  fly: true,
  swim: true, // error
}

Playground

This makes very little sense given your example. You can replace it with just type GenericPick<T> = T and you still get an error on swim. See this playground link. Furthermore, your Extract version actually removes things like name from the type, so you get an error on that, as shown in this playground link. Is this really what you're trying to do? If so, you should edit the question to make that explicit.

I'm sorry, I am not sure how to make it more explicit as it is specified at the top of the description "I want to get a subset of specific/predefined properties... the predefined/specific properties may or may not exist on the provided Type, but if they don't we should not be allowed to assign it on the return type." but if you have any idea how to make it more clear don't hesitate.
